# Good alternatives to Gist that don't require an account for comments/collaboration?

Tags: github, gist

I'm wondering if there exists a comparable alternative to Gist but with a "guest" feature. Essentially Gist without the need for an account to   collaborate or comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." You can read  more about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Checkout http://dontpad.com/